# 2005 Kia Amanti electronic systems turn on randomly without key in car

Tags: ignition, kia, electronics, amanti

What would make my lights flash,  radio come on, doors lock and unlock, seats move at random times day and night when you are not in car and key is not in ignition?

Also my service engine light is not on to say that I have any problems and it does work,  so where does my problem lie?

Comment: The Toyota of a friend of mine is having broadly similar problems.  The main dealer is trying to fix it.

Comment: These type of problems are usually related to water incursion. Body control computer or fuse/relay box are the two most common places. Fill either one with water and bad things happens. Mazda 6 had problems with the hood release cable grommet popping out. Water would then fill up the Body control computer. Then the horn would blow constantly all the time.

Comment: @Sharon Glenn you should take your car to the mechanic as soon as possible. This is a safety critical issue. The car could shut itself down while driving at high speeds.